# Grails 2.3.0 Not Running

Tags: grails

I have *Grails 2.3.0*, and when I run the command `run-app` I get this message:

```
> | Error Error executing script RunApp:
> _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Delete `target` folder from your app directory.
2. delete `.grails/.slcache` folder (is in your /home).
3. Try `grails run-app` again.

Comment: Why is this the answer? I always recommend people to try this, but I don't have any idea why it happens. It seems to always have to do with closures, like if you are deleting or modifying a closure. But I can't find any JIRA or doc with more information.

Comment: @janDro I don't know why too. Someone gave me that solution and it worked. Maybe the problems are caused by auto recompiling changed code in runtime? I don't have this problem for a long time, but I don't know if it is a result of switching to grails 2.3 or not using auto reloading any more.

Answer (score 3):

Do not work for me. I had to delete the `~/.grails/$version/projects/$projectName/scriptCache` directory files.

And execute `grails clean`, before execute `grails run-app` again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue with GGTS 3.4.0 and Grails 2.3.1.  Following these steps resolved it for me:

1. Delete `<workspace>\ggts-3.4.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.grails.ide.eclipse.core\2.3.1\.slcache`
2. Run `clean`
3. Run `run-app`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to totally empty the .grails directory under my home directory

Answer (score 0):

Do a `grails clean` first. followed by a grails compile and finally `grails --stacktrace --verbose run-app`

Also make sure you copied the new `BuildConfig` into your `conf` directory. I had problems until I did that. The file has a lot of new config that can affect the way things are run

Hope that helps