# Grails 2.3.1 not running

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I have what looks to be exactly the same problem lamented here: 
 [Grails 2.3.0 Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349851/grails-2-3-0-not-running)

However none of the tenetative solutions had any effect.

When I attempt to run

grails clean --stacktrace

I get:

```
    | Environment set to development.
| Error Error executing script Clean: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1 (NOT
E: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
        at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.run(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:39)
        at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:32)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy.run(_GrailsClean_groovy:29)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at Clean.run(Clean.groovy:25)
        at Clean$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:607)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closur
e1
        ... 17 more
| Error Error executing script Clean: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
```

Per the link that I refer to I tried:

- deleting my application's target directory
- deleting my home directory's .grails/.slcache
- deleting my workspace's .metadata.plugins\org.grails.ide.eclipse.core\2.3.1.slcache

Before trying any of those I wiped my grails_home directory and replaced with a redownloaded copy of grails 2.3.1

Reverting Grails 2.1.5 also did not help

Nothing in the stack trace points to anything that I explicitly authored so I'm at a loss for what I might have done wrong.

I'm using/running:

- 64 bit java version 1.7.0_45
- Groovy 2.1.9
- Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, 64-bit OS

I have an arbitrary grails app that I created to refer to the BuidConfig that it refers to since I'm attempting to upgrade from Grails 2.1.5 and that runs

The full stack trace is:

```
    | Loading Grails 2.3.1
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development
| Environment set to development.
| Error Error executing script RunApp: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
    at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.run(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:39)
    at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:32)
    at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at _GrailsClean_groovy.run(_GrailsClean_groovy:29)
    at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy.run(_GrailsWar_groovy:27)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.run(_GrailsRun_groovy:28)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at RunApp.run(RunApp.groovy:25)
    at RunApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:607)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:769)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:571)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:470)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:51)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 72 more
| Error Error executing script RunApp: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
```

Comment: can you post your full stacktrace?

Comment: I edited to add the full stacktrace since it was too long to fit into comments along with the caveat that the circumstance was not grails version specific

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **grails.project.work.dir** - which by default would be something like `~/.grails/projects/${appName}` had a directory named: "**scriptCache**"

Emptying the **scriptCache** contents enabled me to move forward.