# Suddenly Grails/GGTS is unable to resolve many classes. How to solve it?

Tags: java, spring, grails, ggts

I'm using GGTS 3.6.4. I tried to include a class, as normally I do and all dependencies crash. I tried to clean the project, refresh its dependencies and re-compile, but all I have is the error below.

Running the project is useless: IDE just alert me about "Errors in exist required project(s)", then the launching suddently stops, without any alert.

All services are alerting that they are "unable to resolve class", as you can see in the picture. What else could be checked?

[image]

**EDIT**

*Action #1*: `refresh-dependencies` > `compile`:

- `refresh-dependencies` generates in my console `|Configuring classpath |Dependencies refreshed`.
- `compile` gives me the alert that we can see at the picture

*Action #2*: `clean-all` > `refresh-dependencies` > `compile`:

- `clean-all` generates `|Application cleaned.`
- `refresh-dependencies` generates `|Installing ([MANY PLUGINS HERE!!!]) |Dependencies refreshed`
- `compile` generates `|Compiling N source files` then there's an error `Compilation error: startup failed` and the first one is `unable to resolve class Transactional`. Can this first error holding all compiling process? Then it brings me the alert in the picture.

*Action #3*: `grails run-app --verbose` by DOS prompt (Win7) generates:

```
C:\Grails_IDE\workspace\vs3>grails run-app --verbose
Base Directory: C:\Grails_IDE\workspace\vs3
| Environment set to development.
| Error Error executing script RunApp: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
        at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.run(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:39)
        at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:116)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:32)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:116)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy.run(_GrailsClean_groovy:29)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at _GrailsWar_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:116)
        at _GrailsWar_groovy.run(_GrailsWar_groovy:27)
        at _GrailsWar_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:116)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.run(_GrailsRun_groovy:28)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:112)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:116)
        at RunApp.run(RunApp.groovy:25)
        at RunApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi
teArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCa
llSite.java:112)
        at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:607)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInst
ance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:769)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(G
railsScriptRunner.java:571)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCa
ching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:470)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsS
cript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(Grai
lsScriptRunner.java:378)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRu
nner.java:226)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Refl
ectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(Grail
sStarter.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStart
er.java:263)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Refl
ectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(Grail
sStarter.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStart
er.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closur
e1
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(Gra
ilsRootLoader.java:51)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 72 more
| Error Error executing script RunApp: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1

C:\Grails_IDE\workspace\vs3>
```

Comment: I don't think so straight after it says it can't resolve Sql then HttpSession and so on. I have found GGTS to be rather intense and may not be so good when you are in this sort of a situation. Try coming out launch a command line console configure JDK and grails version then go into the app and try grails clean grails run-app see how that goes. I tend to use Linux but when forced to use windows I use cygwin to control and configure grails java etc.I have had situations when CLI clears up problem then loading up ggts appears to be ok. GGTS takes up a lot of memory

Comment: @vahid u mean, setting JDK by Linux console. Well, in this company, we still use Windows :( But let me see if I understand what u r saying: 1) configure JDK and Grails version again; 2) Go into the app, clean and run it. Is it right?

Comment: no need to configure JDK Grails for your IDE. As a test create a new work space then copy project into the workspace then create new app in workspace as existing name see if that makes a diff. In this situation dropping CLI see what grails is really saying, also try run-app --stracktrace. I have faced issues with STS and GGTS in a large app which then fails to start up CLI clean and run-app has then fixed the issue. I have found ultimate config for STS.ini that has left me in peace for a while maybe its worth sharing although I still have to sometimes drop CLI when it is a clean start

Comment: Well, I've copied the project for a new workspace (I properly copied it, I mean, I imported it from the current workspace, not only pointing but copying it) and then I tried to run it. I had the same error. I've tried refresh its dependencies and clean the project too, but unsuccessfully. Any other suggestions @vahid?

Comment: no way you can do the grails run-app from CLI msdos prompt ? http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-setup-your-windows-development-environment/ I highly recommend running grails without the overhead of the IDE to get a better insight as to what grails is complaining about if anything

Comment: @vahid I tried run it by prompt as u said and I included the results in the question. It generates the same errors, but I guess we can analyze them better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806712/grails-2-3-4-error-executing-script-clean-grailsclasspath-groovy-run-closur  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813927/grails-2-3-1-not-running http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357224/unable-to-build-grails-app try the 3rd link the last comment is where I would start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113448/discussion-between-victor-f-and-vahid).