# Grails error executing script runapp _grailsclasspath_groovy$_run_closure1

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

Everytime I run the grails application using

```
run-app
```

It runs fine but if I stop it using

```
stop-app
```

Then it stops but gives me the following error if i try to run it again or execute any other commands

```
 error executing script runapp _grailsclasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
```

I have to delete all files manually from `target>work>scriptCache` for things to work again everytime.
Is there any misconfig?
I also tried `clean` after stopping application but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

If you run `clean` in interactive mode it can lead to this error

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you faced this in **Eclipse** environment. I too was facing the same.

This worked for me:

1. Delete `target` folder
2. Delete contents of `.grails` folder
3. Executing `run-app` from command prompt instead of through eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the `.grails` folder (under the user home folder)
2. Delete the `target` folder (under the project folder)
3. Run `clean`
4. Run `run-app`

Example:

```
rm -rf ~/.grails/               # 1.
rm -rf <path to project>/target # 2.
grails clean                    # 3.
grails run-app                  # 4.
```

Reference: [grails-2-3-0-not-running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349851/grails-2-3-0-not-running).